# How to get and show the contents of other HTML page with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, get

I'm a newbie with Jquery. I'm trying to get how to get the contents and show another HTML.

Here is my code that does not work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="target">
        click here to see test1.html
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#target').click(function() {
            $.get('test1.html', function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
                alert('Load was performed.');
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question... How can I get this working. I have read the documentation but I'm not getting if I must use some external script(PHP) to accomplish this.

If you can give me some clues I would be very appreciated.

Update:

I have successfully achieved the task of getting an internal webpage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="target">
        click here to see teste1.html
    </div>
    <div id="result">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#target').click(function() {
            $.get('teste1.html', function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                alert('Load was performed.');
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The main goal is to get an external webpage, but this is not working:

```
$.get('http://www.google.com/index.html', function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Some clues on how to achieve this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is you have no output element, you have `$('.result')`, but you have no `class="result"` element for it to find/put the content in.

Also keep in mind that [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML) (what you're ultimately using here) varies by implementation, meaning various contents of the document (`<head>`, `<script>`, etc.) may be stripped out when inserting it into an element in your page.